# Does node.js, backbone, socketio and express and coffee script all go together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I'm trying to get an overview of what's latest and greatest, and was curious how all these different technologies fit together.

Is it like this:

Nodejs is a webserver, backbone is just a framework that will run on nodejs?

SocketIO is a library that works with backbone then?

And the actual code can be written in coffescript, which when compiled, will be javascript.

What about express then?  Could this be used.

Please point out if these are components/frameworks that don't work together etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, CoffeeScript will work with Node.js without problem.  In fact, if you you use the default coffee executable, it is Node.js and you don't even need to compile to JavaScript in order to run it.

As for Backbone, it is really a client-side library.  You can also use CoffeeScript here, but you need to compile the code to JavaScript since the browsers only know JS.  You wouldn't typically run Backbone.js in Node.

As for Express, it is a Node framework, so it is expected to work on the server in Node.js.

So, in summary:

- You'd use Node server-side with SocketIO and Express
- CoffeScript can go client and server
- You would use Backbone on the client
- You would likely use a Backbone.sync mechanism for talking from Backbone models to SocketIO on the server

Does that help?

Comment: Although Backbone will run happily on `node.js` if required: https://github.com/andyet/capsule

Comment: +1 Certainly, you can.  I tried to choose my words carefully enough that I am not saying that you can't... just that you typically don't.  Interesting link!

Answer (score 4):

[**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/) is a server side implementation of javascript.

[**Express**](http://expressjs.com/) is a web framework that sits on top of connect, another nodejs module.

[**CoffeeScript**](http://coffeescript.org/) can be installed as a module to node.js that allows you to execute coffeescript code directly in node.js.

[**Backbone**](http://backbonejs.org/) is a client-side browser library that has nothing to do with node.js and can be used with any server-side web framework.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about backbone but zappa (http://zappajs.org/) is the sample of coffeescript + express + SocketIO.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, infact here is a great article showing how you can reuse your backbone.js models on the backend.

http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/

Comment: The author has packaged this concept into `capsule.js`: https://github.com/andyet/capsule

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "express" is, but everything else you've mentioned plays well together.

there's a project to replace the `Backbone.Sync` code (which is what does all of the calls to the back-end server in Backbone) with an implementation that uses Socket.io: https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind

a lot of people write backbone code in coffeescript. you'll find a lot of examples of that around the web, including here on stackoverflow.

hope that helps.